# Why does the IIS7 behaves differently through invoke-command?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, invoke-command, appcmd

I have observed this strange behaviour of IIS7 CLI utility appcmd when invoked through invoke-command.

Here is a small piece of command I'm trying to execute.

```
PS C:\>appcmd list config /section:applicationPools | Select-String -SimpleMatch "SomeAppPool" -context 0,4 | Out-String -Stream | Select-String " pingingEnabled=""true"""
```

The command executes perfectly fine [done on the IIS7 machine where all the %PATH% variables are set]. I get an output like

```
<processModel pingingEnabled="true" />
```

The same thing done through invoke-command from a remote machine.

Remote Version-I

```
PS C:\>invoke-command -computername iismachine -credential $creds -scriptblock {
    appcmd list config /section:applicationPools | Select-String -SimpleMatch "SomeAppPool" -context 0,4 | Out-String -Stream | Select-String " pingingEnabled=""true"""
}
```

There is no output but just three empty lines!!!

Although if I do it by creating a remote powershell session, It starts working fine..

Remote Version-II

```
PS C:\>enter-pssession -computername iismachine -credential $creds;
[iismachine]: PS C:\Users\onewildgamer\Documents>invoke-command -scriptblock {
    appcmd list config /section:applicationPools | Select-String -SimpleMatch "SomeAppPool" -context 0,4 | Out-String -Stream | Select-String " pingingEnabled=""true""" 
}
```

Now that there is a difference in behaviour, I don't suspect user permissions issue.

Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong. I can't figure out for the life of me why this wouldn't be working.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this is in fact a permissions and/or double-hop issue.

First, Remote Version-II is not executing on the remote machine. Calling `Invoke-Command` without a `-ComputerName` or `-PSSession` parameter executes the scriptblock on the local machine.

The correct way to start a session first is to use `New-PSSession` and then pass its return value to the `-PSSession` parameter of `Invoke-Command`:

```powershell
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName iismachine -Credential $creds
Invoke-Command -PSSession $session -ScriptBlock { #code }
```

If you try it that way, it's likely that you'll see it stop working.

### Troubleshooting:

```powershell
Invoke-Command -computername iismachine -credential $creds -scriptblock {
    appcmd list config /section:applicationPools # | Select-String -SimpleMatch "SomeAppPool" -context 0,4 | Out-String -Stream | Select-String " pingingEnabled=""true"""
}
```

This comments out all the other stuff, which I think might be masking an error message. By running it this way you should see the raw output, and maybe get a better idea of what's going on.

Often with `Invoke-Command` you'll run into a double hop authentication problem whereby the command you run in the remote session attempts to authenticate to a resource using the current credentials and is unable to. This can sometimes be the case even if the resource is not remote to the remote machine, and IIS is one of those cases where I have seen this.

It's also possible that the `appcmd` invocation is successful, but that its output is different in a way you didn't expect, and your `Select-String` calls are masking this by giving you blank lines.

Comment: The invoke-command in remote version-II infact is inside the remote machine's prompt. Which I forgot to add. I'll edit it right away.

Comment: Understood. I still think you try the troubleshooting code to see what the raw output is.

Comment: Using invoke-command with a pssession didn't make any difference. Tried commenting out the rest of the part, it gave out the whole xml section. Another interesting thing is that using write-host to print the output of complete command without removing pipes is printing the output, but still I don't get why this by default doesn't produce any output.